# Access locally scoped variables from within a string using parse or value (KDB / Q)

Tags: kdb

The following lines of Q code all throw an error, because when the statement "local" is parsed, the local variable is not in the correct scope.

```
{local:1; value "local"}[]
{[local]; value "local"}[1]
{local:1; eval parse "local"}[]
{[local]; eval parse "local"}[1]
```

Is there a way to reach the local variable from inside the parsed string?

Note: This is a simplification of the actual problem I'm grappling with, which is to write a function that executes a query, accepting a list of columns which it should return. I imagine the finished product looking something like this:

```
getData:{[requiredColumns, condition]
    value "select ",(", " sv string[requiredColumns])," from myTable where someCol=condition"
    }
```

The `condition` parameter in this query is the one that isn’t recognised and I do realise I could append it’s value rather than reference it inside a string, but the real query uses lots of local variables including tables etc, so it’s not as easy as just pulling all the variables out of the string before calling `value` on it.

I'm new to KDB and Q, so if anyone has a better way to achieve the same effect I'm happy to be schooled on the proper way to achieve this outcome in Q. Would still be interested to know in the variable access thing is possible though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, you are right that local is not within the  correct scope, as value is looking for the global variable local.

One way to get around this is to use a namespace, which will define the variable globally, but can only be accessed by calling that namespace. In the modified example below I have defined local in the `.ns` namespace

```
{.ns.local:1; value ".ns.local"}[]
```

For the problem you are facing with selecting, if `requiredColumns` is a symbol list of columns you can just use the take operator `#` to select them.

```
getData:{[requiredColumns] requiredColumns#myTable}
```

For more advanced queries using variables you may have to use functional select form, explained [here](https://code.kx.com/v2/basics/funsql/). This will allow you to include variables in the where and by clause of the select statement

The same example in functional form would be (no by clause, only select and where):

```
getData:{[requiredColumns;condition] requiredColumns:(), requiredColumns;
?[myTable;enlist (=;`someCol;condition);0b;requiredColumns!requiredColumns]}
```

The first line ensures that `requiredColumns` is a list even if the user enters a single column name

Comment: Thanks so much - I started editing my question for clarity before reading this answer but it looks good - on my phone at the moment but will try when I get home

Comment: When you use value on the string statement, it is looking for a column `condition` which likely doesn't exist. I have changed my functional select to include the `where someCol=condition`. The second argument of ? takes a list of conditions in parse tree form which is described in this [whitepaper](https://code.kx.com/v2/wp/parse_trees_and_functional_forms.pdf). Since we only have one condition I have enlisted it to make it a list. The where clause uses a fixed column `someCol` and the variable `condition` to equate against

Comment: Thanks Mark - so it turned out that using that requiredColumns#myTable trick was exactly what I needed and I was able to get my existing query working with very minimal changes. I'm confident the other (functional select) solution would have worked too but the first solution was the most readable for me so I went with that.

Comment: Just in case anyone else is reading this and considering the same solution - I started out with the take operator which was an easy fix, but ended up switching to the functional select form after the the performance advantage of the latter was explained to me (the take operator is applied after the query has been executed reading all the columns whereas the functional select approach limits the amount of data read in the first place, which matters for large volumes of data stored on disk).

Answer (score 2):

`value` will look for a variable in the global scope that's why you are getting an error. You can directly use local variables like you are doing that in your function.

Your function is mostly correct, just need a slight correction to append condition(I have mentioned that below). However, a better approach would be to use [functional select](https://code.kx.com/v2/basics/funsql/#select) in this case.

**[Using functional select](https://code.kx.com/v2/basics/funsql/#select):**

```
   q) t:([]id:`a`b; val:3 4)
   q) gd: {?[`t;enlist (=;`val;y);0b;((),x)!(),x]}
   q) gd[`id;3]   / for single column
```

Output:

```
id
-
1
```

```
  q) gd[`id`val;3] / for multiple columns
```

In case your condition column is of type symbol, then enlist your condition value like:

```
  q) gd: {?[`t;enlist (=;`id;y);0b;((),x)!(),x]}
  q) gd[`id;enlist `a]
```

You can use `parse` to get a functional form of `qsql` queries:

```
q) parse " select id,val from t where id=`a"
```

```
?
`t
,,(=;`id;,`a)
0b
`id`val!`id`val
```

**Using String concat(your function):**

```
q)getData:{[requiredColumns;condition] value "select ",(", " sv string[requiredColumns])," from t where id=", .Q.s1 condition}
q) getData[enlist `id;`a] / for single column
q) getData[`id`val;`a]  / for multi columns
```

Comment: Thanks for this also - looks like a workable solution too - will try it and get back to you, cheers

Comment: I have updated the answer based on your updates in the question.

Comment: Thanks very much Rahul. I ended up using the requiredColumns#myTable trick because that solved my problem simply and easily, but it's great to see how I could have done it using both functional select and string concatenation. There's always more than one way to do these things and I really appreciate the input ;)